# Volvo c30 D5 electrical issues

Tags: electrical, volvo, abs

I've had the dreaded "brake failure - stop safely" error message on my volvo c30 D5 2007, It appears to be a common fault amongst volvos.

It's a recurring problem that happens 3-4 times a week under no specific circumstances, I know it's an electrical issue because i've replaced both ABS sensors multiple times.

This is the process of what happens and how it resolves itself:

1. Red warning triangle comes up on dashboard with the error messages 
   "Brake failure - stop safely" along with "anti-skid service required" and "immobiliser", occasionally the "power steering failure" fault comes up as well.
2. The car does not allow you to accelerate, The indicators stop working and the windscreen wipers come on.
3. I then pull the car over, disconnect the battery for 5-10 seconds and then re-connect it.
4. 9/10 times the car starts working fine again without any warnings, the other 1/10 times i have to repeat step 3 multiple times until it decides to work.
5. continue driving as normal for the rest of the journey.

I've tried having the fault codes read by both volvo and independent garages, neither could find any fault codes (probably due to having to disconnect the battery to get it to work again)

After reading through hundreds of threads online regarding the issue it appears the fault can be be down to 3 things:

1. Faulty/water damaged CEM
2. Faulty/water damaged ABS module
3. Faulty/water damaged DIM module

Problem being replacing just one of those costs allot of money, especially if it doesn't cure the problem and i have to then replace another one as well.

So i have 2 questions which I cant seem to find the answers to online

1. Could this fault be down to anything other than the 3 modules i've mentioned above ?
2. Where can i locate each of the 3 modules I mentioned above, I know the CEM is in the passenger footwell but unsure as to where the ABS and DIM modules are ?